# Mysqldump via ShellExecute not working

Tags: delphi, mysql

I am trying to backup my mysql database from delphi by using ShellExecute to run mysqldump.
This is how I am using mysqldump:

```
MySqlDump.exe -u root  -p[password]  [databasename] > TheOutputFile.Sql
```

This works from command prompt.

I call this command line using ShellExecute:

```
  ShellExecute(
    0,
    nil,
    'cmd.exe',
    'C:\SmartRetail\Test System\Periodic database backup\MySqlDump.exe -u root -p123    smartretailprogramdata > TheOutputFile2.Sql',
    nil,
    SW_SHOW
    );
```

This does not work, instead it opens command prompt.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: So, why do you execute `cmd.exe` and not directly `MySqlDump.exe` ?

Comment: I have never used ShellExecute before and i copied the code from another website.

Comment: @TLama To get cmd to do stdout redirection.

Comment: Rather than mess around with file redirection, I'd use the [`result-file`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_result-file) option.

Answer (score 0):

It opens the command interpreter because that's what `cmd.exe` is. You need to specify `/C` to tell the cmd process to close after it has interpreted your commands.

On top of that you need to take care of the working directory. Unless the .sql file is in the working directory, the dump process will not find it. And the working directory is inherited from the parent process since you did not specify it. You may need to specify the working directory.

Finally, `ShellExecute` is really the wrong solution here. You are only using it to get the stdout redirection. But that should really be done explicitly. Use `CreateProcess` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Of curse you can :

```
var
    BatFile : TStringList;
    str: string;
const 
    EXEC  = 'MySqlDump.exe -u root  -p[password]  [databasename] > TheOutputFile.Sql' ;
begin
    BatFile := TStringList.Create;
    BatFile.Text := EXEC ;
    str := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 's.bat';
    BatFile.SaveToFile(str);
    BatFile.Free;
    ShellExecuteW(Handle, 'open', PWideChar(str), nil, nil, SW_HIDE);
    Sleep(200);
    ShowMessage('Done.');
    DeleteFile(str);
end;
```